# Consolidating Repetative Jquery Script

Tags: php, jquery

Preface: I went through every question I could find on Stack and couldn't make this work.

I have a hover script that functions sort of like an image gallery, and when you hover over links, its supposed to hide the sibling images and display the correct one that related to the link you hovered over.

It gets all the data with PHP

```
    <section id="callouts" class="clearfix">
    <div class="fltLeft span_1_of_2">
        <h2>Popular Products</h2>
           <div id="productImages">
              <?php 
                  $counter = 0; 
                $products = get_field('popular_products'); if($products) { foreach ($products as $product) { $counter = $counter + 1; ?>
                <img class="image-<?php echo $counter; ?>" src="<?php echo $product['product_thumbnail'] ?>">       
            <?php }; } ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
            $counter = 0; 
            $products = get_field('popular_products'); if($products) { echo '<ul id="prodList">'; foreach ($products as $product) { $counter = $counter + 1; ?>
            <li class="product-<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php echo $product['product_name'] ?></li>     
        <?php } echo '</ul>'; } ?>
    </div>
    <div id="shipping" class="fltRight span_1_of_2"></div>
    </section>
```

and it produces this html:

```
    <section id="callouts" class="clearfix">
    <div class="fltLeft span_1_of_2">
        <h2>Popular Products</h2>
        <div id="productImages">
                                <img class="image-1" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-stationary.png">      
                                <img class="image-2" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-business-cards.png">      
                                <img class="image-3" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-brochures.png">       
                                <img class="image-4" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-newsletters.png">     
                                <img class="image-5" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-presentations.png">       
                                <img class="image-6" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-posters.png">     
                                <img class="image-7" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/popular-postcards.png">       
                        </div>
        <ul id="prodList">              <li class="product-1">Business Stationary<br><br></li>      
                        <li class="product-2">Business Cards<br>   <br></li>        
                        <li class="product-3">Brochures & Flyers<br><br></li>       
                        <li class="product-4">Newsletters &<br>Event Programs</li>      
                        <li class="product-5">Presentations<br><br></li>        
                        <li class="product-6">Posters & Signs<br><br></li>      
                        <li class="product-7">Postcards & Rackcards<br><br></li>        
        </ul>           </div>
    <div id="shipping" class="fltRight span_1_of_2"></div>
</section>
```

The only way I can get this to work is by repeating my jquery script over and over:

```
$('.product-1').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-1').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-1').siblings().hide();
    }
);
$('.product-2').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-2').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-2').siblings().hide();
    }
);
$('.product-3').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-3').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-3').siblings().hide();
    }
);
$('.product-4').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-4').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-4').siblings().hide();
    }
);
$('.product-5').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-5').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-5').siblings().hide();
    }
);
$('.product-6').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-6').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-6').siblings().hide();
    }
);
$('.product-7').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image-7').fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image-7').siblings().hide();
    }
);
```

Which is a totally lame way to do this. I need help rewriting this, and if possible an awesome explanation of what you did and why. Thank you so much!

Comment: The only difference among the repetitions is a numeric suffix in the strings, which you can trivially automate with a loop and `'string' + i` instead of `string1`, `string2` etc. In any case, this should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have heard of loops, but I'm trying to figure out if I even need the counter? Many answers to this sort of question on Stack don't have this. They just remove it and use the class or a data attr in the script... which is why I haven't been successful in finding a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convertig it into a loop wasn't as trivial as it looked like, as i is not available in the context fo the event handlers anymore, so you ahve to use IIFE to create the handler functions while evaluating i in place. But there you go:

```
for (var i = 1 ; i <= 7 ; i++ ) {
    $('.product-'+i).hover((function (num) {
        return function () {
            $('.image-'+num).fadeIn("fast");
            $('.image-'+num).siblings().hide();
        };
    })(i))
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution first, since this didn't require me changing my PHP at all, and I couldn't get it working. Any other thoughts? I posted a jsfiddle above with the old code, but feel free to fork it/tweak if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Getting any errors with my solution? tried `alert()`ing `num`inside the event handlers to see if a) handlers get registered and b) num gets assigend the right value? 'cause I may have mad a mistake there ;) I'm on my phone right now, so jsFiddle'ing myself isn't possible right now, sorry.

Comment: I did get this error: TypeError: $(...).hover(...) is not a function
 

})(i);

Comment: YESS! That's the stuff. So do you find this to be the most efficient way to do it? This def works and is way cleaner than how I had it before.

Comment: It's clearly not cleanest way, as it still involves using all those classes - which normally should only have a meaning for styling, not storing data. But if you prefer not to touch the PHP code, it doesn't get shorter that that. If you're up for the smallest bit of performance, get rid of jQuery and use plain JS - it may half execution times, but as those are normally only a few ms, that won't matter much I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `data-` element to hold a value and generalize the function.

```
<li class="product" data-img='image5'>Business Cards</li>
```

JS:

```
$('.product').hover(
    function () {
        var targ = $(this).data('img');
        $(targ).fadeIn("fast");
        $(targ).siblings().hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: Tried this, and still having trouble. Set up a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ftsor11/RPF5e/

Comment: You're using class="image-7" on your images, but "image1" in your data element. They must match.

Comment: OK, I got this to work as well after changing the class. Thank you!